# Unix/Linux cat x y > y : is my understanding of the processing correct?

Tags: linux, unix, cat, io-redirection

I'm currently working through Kernighan and Pike's excellent book *The UNIX Programming Environment*. One interesting example they give (Exercise 3-7) is the command

```
cat x y > y
```

I tried running this command with the initial contents of the files being `x` contains `xxx` and `y` contains `yyy`:

The command does not complete. `x` remains unchanged (as you would expect) and `y` ends up with an large number of lines of `xxx`.

This is how I've rationalised the behaviour:

1. First thing the `>` redirection operator does is truncate `y` ready to receive the redirect data. Hence no `yyy` bytes end up in `y`.
2. As `y` is empty when the redirect process starts writing data., the output of `cat x y` (initially) is just `xxx`.
3. `cat` will not stop writing until it reaches EOF on `y`. But it never reaches EOF, because as each write operation completes, it pushes EOF further past the current read/write pointers? So `cat` keeps appending `y` to itself indefinitely.

If anyone could provide a more articulate (and less handwavy) explanation of this behaviour, or correct me if this is total rubbish, that would be much appreciated.

Also I'm sure at one point I found a set of worked solutions online for the problems in this textbook, but I can't find them now. If anyone could point me to such a thing, that would be great.

Many thanks,

MB

Comment: you overwrote the contents of file y.

Comment: which version of `cat` are you using? gnu cat 8.21 dumps x's contents into `y`, then aborts with `cat: y: input file is output file`

Comment: using cat 8.23. when you stated in 2nd point, y is empty, it is overwritten with contents of x, which in turn yields the message `$ cat x y > y
cat: y: input file is output file'

Comment: @Marc B - I'm using OSX cat. @Charles Duffy - I will try learning about `strace` - sounds useful :-) ... *looks into it* ... uh oh, `strace` isn't available for OSX ... I'll have to research an equivalent. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: See if you have `truss` or `dtruss`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, your existing understanding is correct.**

To look at the actual syscalls (from `strace busybox cat x y >y`, to avoid the GNU version's attempts at detecting and terminating such loops):

```
open("x", O_RDONLY)                     = 3
read(3, "xxx\n", 4096)                  = 4
write(1, "xxx\n", 4)                    = 4
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("y", O_RDONLY)                     = 3
read(3, "xxx\n", 4096)                  = 4
write(1, "xxx\n", 4)                    = 4
read(3, "xxx\n", 4096)                  = 4
write(1, "xxx\n", 4)                    = 4
```

...and the final two lines repeat ad infinitum.

Not shown is the outer shell's `open("y", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666)`, done after the `fork()` to spawn the subprocess which then exec's cat but before `cat`'s actual execution -- and thus, before all of the above.

Thus, we see exactly what you posited: Only a single line of `xxx`s is available for read *until* cat performs a write, at which point additional content is immediately available for read, so the loop proceeds.